# Identifying a C function start and end using c#

Tags: c#

I have a program, written in C#, that when given a tow C files, counts the lines in the tow files, I want to add the ability to count how many functions are in the files , how many lines are in those functions and the difference between the 2 functions in file 1 and file 2. I can't figure out how to determine whether a line is the start of a function (or method).

Comment: Not trivial in the general case. You need to parse the C file, i.e. implement a C parser (know the rues for a syntactically correct C prog etc.). If you can make assumptions about your files (no preprocessing, no braces in comments etc.) it may be doable ad-hoc.

Comment: Regular Expressions maybe? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx
Something similar to this to find headers: "\w+ \w+\(.*\)".
You can test at regexpal or something similar. 

Not sure if this is the best option tho.. and it will be slow, yes.

Comment: To give you an idea: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

Comment: If you are primarily trying to diff similar pieces of code, I would recommend using a tool designed explicitly for this purpose. Have you looked into using a program such as WinMerge? There is also a lower-level package called diffutils which can do the same thing in a more scriptable fashion.